# VS 2017 Package Load Errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

VS 2017 is almost unusable, I get unending stream of errors, solutions not loading properly etc, all errors point to one file.
Mainly containing:

`SetSite failed for package[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage](null)`
and `End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.EditorPackage]`

See attached XML.
https://app.box.com/s/a9lt4po5nmsw6b30zwrzhloirddl6igz

Comment: Hi, looks like you had a number of install errors. Can you please run http://aka.ms/vscollect.exe and post your logs somewhere where we can take a look? Thanks! (Disclosure: I work on Visual Studio at Microsoft)

Comment: I restarted Visual Studio and now everything works perfectly, wonder what that was.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar errors. So after a quick research I found that it has to do with settings and package cache, so the following solved it

1. Removed %appdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio and %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio (after taking a backup)
2. Restarted Visual Studio (preferred as an administrator)